# How does the mirror clock work in an accelerating spacecraft?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, reference-frames, acceleration, time-dilation

I recall Feynman explaining time dilation in a moving spacecraft using a clock which counts reflecting light. As I understand it, to a stationary observer the path the light takes is longer than it is to the observer aboard the ship and this accounts for slower clocks and indeed all processes, so this causes time dilation. (I realize there is more to it than that, but this is basically what Feynman said.)

In the case of the accelerating spacecraft, the path would again be longer I think but it would not be longer by a constant but I think would get longer over time. Is time dilation approximately the same as it would be in a constantly-moving spacecraft at the moment the light returns from being reflected? Or is it more complex?

Answer (score 0):

Light clocks don't cause time dilation. The point of the light clock thought experiment is to show that time dilation can be induced from the necessity of making the events transpire as detected with constant speed of light.

For a linearly accelerated pair of mirrors, there is no inertial frame for which events are in the same place, but if we pick an observer who is initially comoving with the accelerated pair, we note that in order for the light to strike the same place on the mirrors as the mirrors accelerate, while preserving the laws of reflection, we must angle the mirrors "upward".

Below is a crude sketch with hugely exaggerated angles. The angle of the mirrors should be fixed and symmetrical, with angle of incidence matching angle of reflection.

[image]

If you adopt a non-inertial frame in which the two mirrors never move, it'll look like the straight lines traveled by the laser beam are a back-and-forth parabola, like playing catch with a ball.

[image]

Keep in mind that any angle big enough to depict in a sketch like this would require an acceleration (boosting up to close to the speed of light relative to the initially comoving observer within a few ticks of the clock) that would instantly destroy any real experimental apparatus, even if the mechanical power to attempt it could be found.

Comment: who said that clocks cause the slowing of time?